# Uploading Error in docx file but able to upload pdf in same code

Tags: php, file-upload

Am tried to upload docx file format and xlsx it not moving file to location it throwing error. 
here the code for uploading

```
/*     Upload Pdf  */
    if(isset($_FILES["file"]) && $_FILES["file"]["error"] == 0){
    $allowed = array('pdf' => "application/pdf",'doc' => "application/msword",'docx'=>'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document');
    $filename = $_FILES["file"]["name"];
    $filetype = $_FILES["file"]["type"];
    $filesize = $_FILES["file"]["size"];

    // Verify file extension
    $ext = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    if(!array_key_exists($ext, $allowed)) die("Error: Please select a valid file format.");

    // Verify file size - 5MB maximum
    $maxsize = 5 * 1024 * 1024;
    if($filesize > $maxsize) die("Error: File size is larger than 5MB the allowed limit.");

    // Verify MYME type of the file
    if(in_array($filetype, $allowed)){
        // Check whether file exists before uploading it
        if(file_exists("../../upload/courses/pdf/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"])){
            unlink("../../upload/courses/pdf/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);

            $tmph = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
            $pathh = "../../upload/courses/pdf/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];

            move_uploaded_file($tmph,$pathh );
        } else{
            $tmph = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
            $pathh = "../../upload/courses/pdf/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];

            move_uploaded_file($tmph,$pathh );
            //echo "Your file was uploaded successfully.";

        } 
    } else{   echo "Error: There was a problem uploading your file. Please try again.";        }




} 
        $filepath =substr("../../upload/courses/pdf/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"],3);

       if($_FILES["file"]["size"] == 0 && $_FILES["file"]["error"] == 4){

        $file ='';
        }
        else{
            $file = ",file='".$filepath."'";
        }
```

> Error in the link  move_uploaded_file() part

By using same file code am able to upload pdf file but cause error in docx and xlsx file format.

Answer (score 0):

On above part i checked MIME with printing filetype, it got me the file mimetype i need to use.
 So i changed

```
$allowed = array('pdf' => "application/pdf",'doc' => "application/msword",'docx'=>'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document');
```

To

```
$allowed = array('pdf' => "application/pdf",'doc' => "application/msword",'docx'=>'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document','docx'=>'application/octet-stream');
```

On my case it worked with this match `'docx'=>'application/octet-stream'`, in-case error mean try to check   `$_FILES["file"]["type"];` by echo or print it.